# Number of ways to write set $S$ as union of $l$ unique $k$-subsets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The $k$-subsets can, of course, overlap. The answer should be in terms of $k,l$ and $|S|=n$. I have a very complicated solution involving inclusion-exclusion in mind, so I thought I'd post here first to see if anyone can think of a simpler answer.

Comment: Is a "$k$-subset" a subset of size $k$?

Comment: Additionally, is it a collection of $l$ subsets, or an ordered list of $l$ subsets? Finally, do the $l$ subsets have to be distinct?

Comment: @6005 Yes, collection, yes. You can just divide/multiply by $l!$ anyway for the collection issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the  Polya Enumeration  Theorem and  the unlabeled  set operator
$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}$
we obtain the generating function

$$Z(P_l)([z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n (1+z A_q)).$$

The cycle index here is evaluated with the rule

$$a_d = [z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n (1+z A_q^d).$$

Now we  need to remove those  terms from the generating  function that
are missing  some of the  $n$ elements  represented by the  $A_q,$ and
this  is  done  by  inclusion-exclusion. We  will  subtract  from  the
generating  function  those  terms  that have  one  or  more  elements
missing, then  add those with  two or more  and so on.   The remaining
terms in  the generating  function are  set to  one. For  $p$ elements
missing  we   set  the  corresponding   variables  to  zero   and  the
substitution becomes

$$a_d = [z^k] (1+z)^{n-p} = {n-p\choose k}.$$

Given that

$$Z(P_l) = [w^l] 
\exp\left(\sum_{d\ge 1} (-1)^{d+1} a_d \frac{w^d}{d}\right)$$

the substituted cycle index becomes

$$[w^l] \exp\left({n-p\choose k} 
\sum_{d\ge 1} (-1)^{d+1} \frac{w^d}{d}\right)
\\ = [w^l] \exp\left({n-p\choose k} \log(1+w)\right)
= [w^l] (1+w)^{n-p\choose k}
\\ = \frac{1}{l!} {n-p\choose k}^{\underline{l}}.$$

Here we have chosen to expand  the second binomial coefficient to make
the formula  easier to read.   Inclusion-exclusion now yields  for the
answer

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{l!} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 
{n-p\choose k}^{\underline{l}}.}$$

In terms of operators we have treated the combinatorial class

$$\textsc{SET}_{=l}(\textsc{SET}_{=k}(
\mathcal{A}_1+\mathcal{A}_2+\cdots+\mathcal{A}_n)).$$

Here  is  the  Maple code  to  compute  these  values  as a  means  of
clarifying the interpretation  of the problem that  was used. (Warning
-- total  enumeration only  practicable for small  configurations. The
latter  routine was  deliberately  left unoptimized  to represent  the
problem statement before processing.)

```
pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l-1)*a[l]*
                   pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

X_CIND :=
proc(n, k, l)
    option remember;
    local gf, gfA, src, idx, term, res;

    src := add(A[q], q=1..n);

    idx := pet_cycleind_set(k);
    gf := expand(pet_varinto_cind(src, idx));

    idx := pet_cycleind_set(l);
    gfA := expand(pet_varinto_cind(gf, idx));

    res := 0;

    for term in gfA do
        if nops(indets(term)) = n then
            res := res + term;
        fi;
    od;

    subs([seq(A[q]=1, q=1..n)], res);
end;

X :=
(n, k, l) ->
add(binomial(n,p)*(-1)^p*binomial(binomial(n-p,k), l),
    p=0..n);

X2 :=
(n, k, l) ->
add(binomial(n,p)*(-1)^p*mul(binomial(n-p,k)-q, q=0..l-1),
    p=0..n)/l!;
```

**Sanity  check I  Dec 3  2016.** When  $l=1$ we  should get  just one
possibility when  $k=n$ and  zero otherwise. To  verify this  we start
from

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p {n-p\choose k}$$

and observe that

$${n\choose p} {n-p\choose k}
= \frac{n!}{p! k! (n-p-k)!}
= {n\choose k} {n-k\choose p}$$

which yields for the sum

$${n\choose k} \sum_{p=0}^n  {n-k\choose p} (-1)^p.$$

We may certainly lower the upper  limit to $n-k$ as the inner binomial
coefficient is zero when $n-k\lt p \le n$ and get

$${n\choose k} \sum_{p=0}^{n-k}  {n-k\choose p} (-1)^p.$$

When $k=n$ this evaluates to

$${n\choose n} [z^0] (1+z)^0 = 1$$

as claimed. Furthermore when $k\lt n$ we get

$${n\choose k} (-1+1)^{n-k} = 0$$

which confirms  the sanity check.  We could  also treat this  with the
Egorychev method, introducing

$${n-p\choose k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n-p} 
\; dz$$

to get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p \frac{1}{(1+z)^p} 
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^n
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} z^n
\; dz.$$

This is $[z^k] z^n$ which is one when $k=n$ and zero otherwise.

Observe furthermore that for $k=1$ the formula produces

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p {n-p\choose l}$$

and we once more get one for $l=n$ and zero otherwise. This is because
we cannot  cover $n$  with singletons  if there are  less than  $n$ of
them.  There is  one possibility  when $l=n$  (one singleton  for each
element of $[n]$).  There are no admissible  configurations when $l\gt
n$  because the  subsets have  to  be unique  and there  are only  $n$
different ones available.

**Sanity check II Dec  3 2016.** We can treat the  case $l=2$ where we
obtain

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p {n-p\choose k}
\left({n-p\choose k} - 1\right)
\\ = -\frac{1}{2} [[n=k]]
+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p {n-p\choose k}^2
\\ = -\frac{1}{2} [[n=k]]
+ \frac{1}{2} {n\choose k} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {n-k\choose p} (-1)^p {n-p\choose k}.$$

Lowering the upper limit to $n-k$ and using the earlier integral (both
as before) we get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose p} (-1)^p \frac{1}{(1+z)^p} 
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{n-k}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2k-n+1}} (1+z)^{k}
\; dz.$$

Therefore we have the closed form

$$-\frac{1}{2} [[n=k]]
+ \frac{1}{2} {n\choose k} 
{k\choose 2k-n}.$$

Counting these from combinatorial  principles suppose $q$ elements are
common to both sets where $0\le  q\le k$, this means that $q+2(k-q)=n$
or $q=2k-n$ for a contribution of

$$\frac{1}{2} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose k-q}
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose 2k-n} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$

Note  however  that  this  produces $\frac{1}{2}  {n\choose  n}  [z^0]
(1+z)^0 = \frac{1}{2}$ when $n=k$ while the correct result is zero (no
possibility for two  unique sets of $n$ elements as  there is only one
available or alternatively we must have  $q\lt n$ because the two sets
are unique) so we finally get

$$-\frac{1}{2} [[n=k]] 
+ \frac{1}{2} {n\choose 2k-n} {2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$

To verify that this matches the result from the integral we write

$${n\choose 2k-n} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
= \frac{n!}{(2k-n)!(n-k)!(n-k)!}
= {n\choose k} {k\choose 2k-n}.$$

Comment: DAMMMMM this is the kind of stuff I need to learn how to do. Is there any way to get that sum into a closed form, though?

Comment: Again, this answer is just absolutely brilliant.

Comment: Also: I'm really interested in getting a lower bound on the sum. Is it possible to substitute the factorials with Stirling's approximation and then integrate? How would one ensure the integrals are a lower bound on the sum? Or would it even be possible to sum directly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an Inclusion-Exclusion solution is so complicated. In fact, it is pretty straightforward.

For each element $x\in S$, define property $P_x$ to be "$x$ does not belong to any subset in a given $l$-collection of $k$-subsets". We want to find the enumerate the number $e_0$ of $l$-collections of $l$ $k$-subsets that satisfy *exactly* $0$ properties in $\Omega=\{P_x\mid x\in S\}$.

Given an arbitrary subset $T$ of $\Omega$, let $N(\supseteq T)$ be the number of $l$-collections of $k$-subsets that satisfy *at least* all the properties in $T$. Let $S_T=\{x\mid P_x\notin T\}$, then all $k$-subsets that satisfy at least all properties in $T$ are subsets of $S_T$. The number of $k$-subsets of $S_T$ is
$$
\binom{|S_T|}{k}=\binom{n-|T|}{k},
$$
so the number of $l$-collections of such subsets is
$$
\binom{\binom{n-|T|}{k}}{l}.
$$
Let
$$
N_j=\sum_{\substack{T\subseteq\Omega\\|T|=j}} N(\supseteq T).
$$
There are $\binom{n}{j}$ subsets $T\in\Omega$ of cardinality $j$, so
$$
N_j=\binom{n}{j}\binom{\binom{n-j}{k}}{l}.
$$
But then the formula (4.2.6) on page 112 of [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf) says that the number we want is
$$
e_0=\sum_{j\ge 0}(-1)^j N_j = \sum_{j\ge 0}(-1)^j \binom{n}{j}\binom{\binom{n-j}{k}}{l}
=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j \binom{n}{j}\binom{\binom{n-j}{k}}{l}.
$$