# There's $M_i$ balls of color $i=1,..,N$. $n$ balls are drawn without replacement. Find: probability that each of the colors is represented

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

An urn contains $M_i$ balls of color $i$ for $i = 1, 2 . . . , N$. A random
sample of size $n$ is drawn from the urn without replacement. Find
the probability that each of the colors is represented.

My thought were counting the wanted draws and dividing them by all possible permutations of choosing $n$ balls without replacement.
Let $M=\sum_{i=1}^N M_i$ be the total amount of balls in the urn.
So the probability would be:
$$ \frac{\prod_{i=1}^N M_i \cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} M-i}{\binom{M}{n}} $$
Would you consider this solution correct? Is there a better one?

Answer (score 6):

We will calculate the complimentary probability $q$ that at least one color is not represented. Let $C_i$ be the event that color $i$ is **not** represented in the draw. Then:

$$q=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^NC_i\right)$$

Let $\mathcal{N}=\{1,\dots,N\}$. Using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we can rewrite that as

$$q=\sum_{k=1}^N\left({(-1)}^{k-1}\sum_{\substack{I\subset\mathcal{N}\\|I|=k}}\mathbb{P}(C_I)\right),$$

where $C_I=\cap_{i \in I}C_i$.

Now we need only calculate the $\mathbb{P}(C_I)$; this is much easier. At the $k$-th step in the draw (there are $n$ steps), $k-1$ balls have already been drawn. The probability that, at the $k$-th step, we **don't** draw from one of the colors in $I$ **given** that we have not drawn from any of the colors in $I$ is

$$p(k,I)=\frac{\big(M-(k-1)\big)-\sum_{i\in I}M_i}{M-(k-1)}=\frac{\left(\sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}\setminus I}M_j\right)-(k-1)}{M-(k-1)}$$

It follows that

$$\mathbb{P}(C_I)=\prod_{k=1}^np(k,I)=\frac{{\left(\sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}\setminus I}M_j\right)}_n}{{(M)}_n}$$

where $(x)_k=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\big(x-(i-1)\big)$ is the falling factorial.

Plugging into the formula for $q$ above, this yields a nasty, but (seemingly) correct answer to the value of $q$, and $p=1-q$.

Comment: You are only using $n$ and $N$ in your formula; what about the OP's variable $M$? An urn with 1 white ball and 1 black ball with two balls being chosen has a much different probability that an urn with 1 white ball and 1000 black balls with two balls being chosen.

Comment: @ChasBrown Oh, you are absolutely correct. Will try and rework the answer.

Comment: @ChasBrown I have edited the answer and I believe it is correct now.

Comment: This looks to be correct and you were the first to post hence (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have $M_q$ balls of color $A_q$ where $1\le q\le N$ and $k$
balls are drawn  without replacement and we ask  about the probability
that each color is represented. We put $M=\sum_q M_q.$

Using      the     same      concept     as      in     this      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039600/)  we  introduce
the generating function

$$[z^k] \prod_{q=1}^N (1+zA_q)^{M_q}.$$

Now when we set  a subset of the $A_q$ to zero we  are left with those
terms   that  are   missing  these   $A_q$  and   possibly  additional
terms. Therefore we can apply inclusion-exclusion to compute the terms
where none  of the $A_q$  is missing. We  subtract those where  one or
more $A_q$  is missing, then add  those where two or  more are missing
and so  on. Finally we  set the remaining $A_q$  to one to  obtain the
count. Putting $A=[N]$ we get

$$[z^k] \sum_{S\subseteq A} (-1)^{|S|} 
(1+z)^{M-\sum_{q\in S} M_q}
\\ = \sum_{S\subseteq A} (-1)^{|S|} 
{M-\sum_{q\in S} M_q\choose k}.$$

We then get for the probability

$${M\choose k}^{-1} \sum_{S\subseteq A} (-1)^{|S|} 
{M-\sum_{q\in S} M_q\choose k}.$$

We have the following Maple program to verify these numbers. The total
enumeration routine implements the problem before optimization -- this
was done deliberately in order to adhere to the problem definition.

```
with(combinat);

CHOOSE :=
proc(Ml, k)
    local choice, src, Mq, tp, count, res, cols;

    src := []; count := 0;

    for tp to nops(Ml) do
        Mq := Ml[tp];

        src :=
        [op(src), seq([tp, q+count], q=1..Mq)];
        count := count + Mq;
    od;

    res := [];

    for choice in choose(src, k) do
        cols := [seq(choice[q][1], q=1..k)];
        res := [op(res), cols];
    od;

    res;
end;

PROB :=
proc(Ml, k)
    option remember;
    local choice, count, N, M;

    count := 0; N := nops(Ml);

    for choice in CHOOSE(Ml, k) do
        if nops(convert(choice, `multiset`)) = N then
            count := count + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    M := add(q, q in Ml);
    count/binomial(M, k);
end;

X :=
proc(Ml, k)
    local res, S, N, rest, M;

    N := nops(Ml); M := add(q, q in Ml);

    res := 0;

    for S in powerset([seq(q, q=1..N)]) do
        rest := M - add(Ml[q], q in S);
        res := res + (-1)^nops(S)*binomial(rest, k);
    od;

    res/binomial(M,k);
end;

X2 :=
proc(Ml, k)
    local res, S, N, rest, M, FF;

    FF := (n, q) -> mul(n-p, p=0..q-1);

    N := nops(Ml); M := add(q, q in Ml);

    res := 0;

    for S in powerset([seq(q, q=1..N)]) do
        rest := M - add(Ml[q], q in S);
        res := res + (-1)^nops(S)*FF(rest, k);
    od;

    res/FF(M, k);
end;
```

Following an idea by @Fimpellizieri we can re-write the formula as

$$\frac{1}{M^{\underline{k}}}
\sum_{S\subseteq A} (-1)^{|S|} 
\left(M-\sum_{q\in S} M_q\right)^{\underline{k}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Total number of ways to draw the balls, $$A = \binom{M}{n}$$

(Note each of the above case is equally likely - And that is very important in this question)

Now we need how many ways can we draw $n$ balls so that there is at least $1$ of each of the $N$ colors.

$b_1 + b_2 + ... +  b_N = n$ where
$1<=b_i<=M_i$

This can be solved trivially (Hint: it the coefficient of $x^n$).
Let there be $k$ unique solutions to the above equation. Please note not all solutions are equally likely.

For each such solution a distribution can be achieved in
$$\prod_{i=1}^N \binom{M_i}{b_i}$$

(Note carefully all the above are equally likely now. This is important - we need to treat the balls as different even if they are of same color)

So, total possible favorable cases is
$$ B = \sum_{1}^k (\prod_{i=1}^N \binom{M_i}{b_i})$$

Probability should be $$A / B$$

----- My old response -----------

@OP - Doesn't look correct. for n = N numerator should be 1.  Isn't it.

I agree with ur denominator

Good question though!

Comment: @Fimepellizieri -  i still dont hv rights to post on ur ans hence posting comment here. ur ans looks wrong to me. an implcit assumption u hv made is tht all distributions r equally likely.

Comment: @OP -  numerator should be (Mi, bi) summed across all i. Here bi is from Fimepellizieri solution. You will have  to sum across all possible solutions. Not sure if there is a closed form solution. Thanks